kendo splitter drag split bar to left ,cause height change
  <link href="styles/classic-silver.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/kendo.ui.core.min.js"></script> 
<div id="class_dlg" title="Doc Category" class="class_dlg">
  <div id="class_splitter"   class="class_splitter"> 
    <div>split1</div>
    <div>split2</div>
   </div>
</div> 
<style>
.class_splitter{
  flex-grow: 1;   
  height:100%; 
} 

</style>
<script>
        this.dlg=$("#class_dlg").kendoDialog({
            modal: true,
            width:800,
            height:600,
            title:'x'
        }); 

        $("#class_splitter").kendoSplitter( {   panes: [ {  size: "500px"}]}); 
</script>


height change
I darg splitter bar to left,splitter height will reduce
if drag to right,splitter height will restore
I want drag splitter bar,height not change

please share a working example on the stack overflow editor where the issue happens
